# How to check connectivity from specific source server to destination server using telnetlib

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, network-programming, telnet

I am trying script the process of checking the connectivity between host/server using telnet in shellscript.
I have understood that we can use telnet to check connectivity to a remote server from our local machine but how to do this when we are given a specific source as well

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Looking at telnetlib i dont see anyway it will allow you to specficy the source address.

Comment: is there other way to implement it in python rather than using telnetlib @ChrisDoyle